# How to structure application to aid testing of sql

Tags: java, testing, design-patterns

I am writing an application - to which I think my design is not great. I use a class called ExposedFunctions which houses my `@WebMethod` logic for requests to my web service. These methods often need to read from an internal cache or go to the database. Therefore I have a DBFactory class which has individual methods for database operations. An example of this structure can be seen below

**ExposedFunctions**

```
@WebService
public class ExposedFunctions {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExposedFunctions.class);
    private DBFactory factory = new DBFactory();


    @WebMethod
    public String register(String username, String password, String email, String firstname, String lastname) {
        if(StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(username) || 
           StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(password) || 
           StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(email) ||
           StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(firstname) || 
           StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(lastname)){
            logger.error("String was null or empty when registering");
        }

        RegistrationStatus status = factory.register(username, password, email, firstname, lastname);
        return status.getValue();
    }
}
```

**DBFactory**

```
public class DBFactory {

    private final BasicDataSource source = new BasicDataSource();
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBFactory.class);

    public DBFactory() {

        try {
            setupConnections();
        } catch (DatabasePropertyException e) {
            logger.info("Unable to load the properties file", e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void setupConnections() throws DatabasePropertyException{
        Properties props = DatabaseUtilities.getDatabaseConnectionProps("/swiped.properties");
        if(props != null){
            source.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            source.setUsername(props.getProperty("username"));
            source.setPassword(props.getProperty("password"));
            source.setUrl(props.getProperty("url_local"));
            source.setMaxActive(-1);
        }else{
            throw new DatabasePropertyException("Unable to load the proeprties file in order to connect to the database - exiting application");
        }
    }

    public RegistrationStatus register(String username, String password, String email, String firstname, String lastname) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (username, password, email, firstname, lastname) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        RegistrationStatus status = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        try {
            conn = source.getConnection();
            st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setString(1, username);
            st.setString(2, password);
            st.setString(3, email);
            st.setString(4, firstname);
            st.setString(5, lastname);
            st.executeUpdate();
            status = RegistrationStatus.SUCCESSFUL;
        }
         catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
            logger.warn("Unable to register user " + username + " as they are already registered");
            return RegistrationStatus.USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED;
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Unable to insert a new user in to the database", e);
            status = RegistrationStatus.FAILED;
        }finally{
            DatabaseUtilities.closeConnection(conn);
            DatabaseUtilities.closePreparedStatement(st);
        }
        return status;
    }
```

This setup makes it very difficult for me to test because 1) DBFactory is tied to a particular database connection - meaning that its very likely the data inside will change and tests will pass and fail irregularly. There is also another concern that DBFactory can reach 2000+ lines of code which isn't ideal either.

Please can someone suggest some way of improving this design so as to increase / maximise my testing efforts and also to help ensure better maintainability and extendability.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are at least 3 levels that you need to test and there needs to be some minor modifications to your code to make it easier:

#### 1.  Unit testing your code that calls `DbFactory`.

It's nice that you have already abstracted the code that actually interacts with the database as this makes it easier to test.  If you modify `ExposedFunctions` so you can pass in or inject a different `DbFactory` instance during tests, then your tests can use a mock `DbFactory`.  The mock factory can make sure your code passes in the correct parameters and you can test various error conditions without actually touching a real database.
All you probably need to do is add a constructor or setter method to modify your dbFactory field:

```
public class ExposedFunctions {

   ...
  private DBFactory factory;

  public ExposedFunctions(){
    this(new DBFactory());
  }

  public ExposedFunctions(DbFactory factory){
     Objects.requireNonNull(factory);
     this.factory = factory;
  }
  ...
}
```

#### 2. Modify your `DbFactory` class to mock out the `Connection`

If you do something similar in your `DbFactory` class so you can mock out the `Connection` then your tests against `DbFactory` also don't have to hit a real database.  By Mocking the Connection and the Statements it returns, you can verify that the correct SQL code is getting executed for the given parameters as well as testing various SQLException conditions to simulate connection or data problems that are otherwise hard to test in the real world.

#### 3. Test against a test (in memory? ) database

It is also a good idea to actually connect to a real database to make sure everything works as part of an integration test.  Don't connect to production though!  You can swap out your connection either by using a different property file or by injecting a different connection object like in #2.  There are libraries such as [dbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) to help working with test databases.  There are also in-memory databases like [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) or [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) which are lightweight and let you run tests faster than connecting to a "regular" database.  However, one word of caution with in-memory dbs, it's not exactly the same enviornment or SQL interpreter as your database vender of choice.  There may be differences in SQL or schema design that might make you think your code works since the test passes, but then something wrong happens in production with the same code.

Hope this helps